# Can I ask a question like "Could you please kindly confirm for me ... ?" in a formal email?

Tags: politeness, irony

After checking the dictionary, I noticed that the usage of "Kindly" in request sentences often expresses a sence of ironic. So I am afraid that my expression might lead to misunderstanding.

Comment: It might seem that way in the more informal, synical crowd. It does sound a little over polite to me but it is perfectly alright if you are really asking.

Comment: How deferential are you trying to be?  I guess I tend to be more direct about these things, so i’d probably just write: “I’d like to confirm that ...”  Nobody would read that and think, “Woah, This guy is out of line- asking without using “please” and “kindly”. I’m gonna disregard him and his impertinence”

Comment: It's a little old-fashioned and formal sounding.  My spouse uses it because they are from another country (we live in the US).  You can use it without fear of it being taken as ironic.  I use it occasionally, e.g. in a formal email that contains a request.

Answer (score -2):

Choose `please` or `kindly`. Doing both moves the tone from polite to needy.

The `please` is leaning towards a request.

The `kindly` is leaning towards a demand.

Also, `for me` is a bit awkward since it creates another prepositional phrase in the sentence, and therefore dilutes the main contents.  I would suggest leaving out `for me`. If the reader needs help understanding that the confirmation should be sent to you specificly, do that in the following sentence with something like "You can send the confirmation to this address." or "I am reachable at this phone number/email."